# How to Install Grub after Installing Windows

Tags: grub-efi

Yes, I know this question maybe has asked often. I searched a lot everywhere and really tried to fix it without annoying you, but I couldn't fix it with boot repair with entering in Ubuntu with a test Version.

So, I installed Ubuntu after I had Windows already everything was fine. I set up Ubuntu really nice I was happy then it happen Windows got full of Bugs and I had to reinstall it. So, it destroyed GRUB and I can't enter Ubuntu any more... the extra thing I have done: I used GParted and formatted the partition on which Grub was installed. So I need help. How do I install only the GRUB the thing that lets me choose what to boot and to choose Ubuntu. When I tried Boot Repair it says I have to deactivate Secure Boot. I deactivated it and it still didn't work.

Best would be if someone would help me get a finished GRUB Copy and Paste and format the partition into the right format to then select it from Windows with something like this:

```
bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
```

Comment: UEFI or BIOS installs? What brand/model system? May be best to see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), the auto fix sometimes can create more issues.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: I think that on a UEFI system there is usually a list of boot options in the "system setup" that you can enter at boot time, by pressing some special key like F2 or whatever. There you can choose between different boot options. Chances are that when you reinstalled Windows it added a new entry there and it became the default -- however, your old grub menu may still be there as well, you just need to enter the "system setup" and choose your boot option and/or make it the default. Note that by "system setup" I mean something that comes before any grub menu.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/rB9Dbpp6sb/

Comment: thanks i solved it somehow i managed to disable secure boot and with boot repair it worked just i don't know why its installed on the stick now so i only get the grub when the stick is plugged :)))